# Hiding and unhiding rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for hiding and unhiding rows in Excel sheet. It is working partly fine but there is a problem with it.

I have sections and they are: 46:42, 41:37, 36:32 and 31:27.

I would like to hide them step by step, so after one button click 46:42 would be hidden, second click 41:37, third click 36:32 and fourth click 31:27.

My current code is unhiding everything fine but on fifth click it suddenly unhides 48:51. What is the problem?

```
Public counter2 As Long

'Unhide step by step on each click

Sub UnhideEducation()

    Dim RngTxt As String, RngAR() As String, ThisRng As String

    counter2 = (counter2 + 1) Mod 5

    ThisRng = "" & (47 - (counter2 * 5)) & ":" & (47 - (counter2 * 5) + 4)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Rows(ThisRng).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Hide everything set counter2to 0

Sub HideEducation()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Unprotect
Rows("27:46").EntireRow.Hidden = True
counter2 = 0
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Protect
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What should it unhide on the fitth click? 46:42?

Comment: I have only 4 sections. On fifth click it should do nothing, also sixth, seventh and so on.

Comment: After you have used FXD's solution do this: **If counter2 >=4 then | counter2 ... | Exit Sub | End If**. But how will you start the counter again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems instead of `counter2 = (counter2 + 1) Mod 5`, you want to do `counter2 = (counter2 Mod 4) + 1`

If you define a number modulo 5, it is expected it will generate 5 steps.
Setting a variable modulo 4 and then adding 1 to it will make it loop from 1 to 4.